# Increasing performance of exec() statement

Tags: php, bash, exec

I have an issue, that is not necessarily in the scope of most questions asked here.

I have an application I am developing that checks a domain for certain A records and also tests ports on the resolving server to check if they are open and listening.

I have added functionality on my local copy of the site, but it is too slow for me to publish, come to think of it, so is the current published site.

You can see the app on the link: http://www.domainion.co.za

Enter a domain name (without www) and it will check for certain records.

This is a symfony app, I am getting these records by running multiple exec() statements with digs for specific information. The reason I like using exec, is because if there are multiple records returned, like the below command, it lets you assign each result to an index of an array.

dig -x 154.0.174.35 +short @8.8.8.8

motairgdiool.hosted.co.za. (index 0)

kent.aserv.co.za. (index 1)

Now, this is taking way too long (on average 8 seconds to load). My issue with this, is if you had to take all these commands in this app and run it in a shell script, they take under a second to run, I suspect the reason mine takes so long, is that PHP is opening and closing a virtual shell for each of these commands.

In an attempt to run these queries quicker, I have tried the below:

**shell_exec()** - This takes about the same time, and returns all results as a string, I can't use that.

**proc_open** - takes longer, also returns a long string.

**symfony process() component** - takes waaay longer and also returns all results as one string

**dns_check_record()** - you can't check for specific subdomain records

TLDR : Is there any way I can get records that i want (*n*.domain.tld) and still have the application run fast?

Thanks

Comment: Opening and closing a virtual shell (i.e. a pty) typically takes less than 0.1 seconds (you can time it with `time script -c true /dev/null`, I get 0.05s). The problem is something else, like slow DNS or throttling.

Comment: Is there a way to convert your comment into an answer? So I can upvote it a thousand times??? I assumed using Google's name servers would be the better option as I trust google more than the IDC that hosts the server. But yeah, removing the @8.8.8.8 almost tripled the speed, and I split the stats page from the regular DNS page to make it even faster. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like you did all the work, so you can post that as an answer if you want. Consider Eric's execless version though, it should save another fraction of a second second while being more robust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ php -r 'var_dump(dns_get_record("35.174.0.154.in-addr.arpa"));'`

Returns the following in under a one fifth of a second, including invoking the PHP interpreter:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(25) "35.174.0.154.in-addr.arpa"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(7192)
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "PTR"
    ["target"]=>
    string(16) "kent.aserv.co.za"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(25) "35.174.0.154.in-addr.arpa"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(7192)
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "PTR"
    ["target"]=>
    string(25) "motairgdiool.hosted.co.za"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use local DNS. It would be faster than a query to @8.8.8.8

```
dig -x 154.0.174.35 +short
```